# how to get an ext.js grid from a database

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

Ive been trying to get a simple Ext.js application to work, that gets its data from a database and displays it in a ext.js grid, but the only thing I always get is "Failure:true".
Maybe you can point out the error to me.

here is the index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="extjs/ext-dev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="mainscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
<body>
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','1234','cdcol') or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$task = '';
if ( isset($_POST['task'])){
    $task = $_POST['task'];
}   
switch($task){
    case "LISTING":              
        getList();
        break;
    default:
        echo "{failure:true}"; 
        break;
}

function getList(){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cdcol.cds");
$cds = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$cds[] = array('titel' => $row['titel'], 'jahr' => $row['jahr'],'interpret' => $row['interpret'], 'id' => $row['id']);
}
$jsonresult = json_encode(array('cds'=>$cds));
}
?>
</body>
```

And this would be the mainscript.js:

```
var cdDataStore;         
var cdColumnModel;       
var cdEditorGrid;
var cdWindow;

Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.QuickTips.init();

cdDataStore = new Ext.data.Store({
  id: 'cdDataStore',
  proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'index.php',      
            method: 'POST'
        }),
        baseParams:{task: "LISTING"},
  reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({   

    root: 'results',
    totalProperty: 'total',
    id: 'id'
  },[ 
    {name: 'titel', type: 'string', mapping: 'titel'},
    {name: 'interpret', type: 'string', mapping: 'interpret'},
    {name: 'jahr', type: 'int', mapping: 'jahr'},
    {name: 'id', type: 'int', mapping: 'id'}
  ]),
  sortInfo:{field: 'jahr', direction: "ASC"}
});

cdColumnModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(
[{
    header: '#',
    readOnly: true,
    dataIndex: 'id', 
    width: 50,
    hidden: false
  },{
    header: 'titel',
    dataIndex: 'titel',
    width: 150,

  },{
    header: 'interpret',
    dataIndex: 'interpret',
    width: 150,

  },{
    header: 'jahr',
    readOnly: true,
    dataIndex: 'jahr',
    width: 50,                    
  },{
    header: 'id',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    width: 150,
    readOnly: true
  }]
);
cdColumnModel.defaultSortable= true;

cdEditorGrid =  new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
  id: 'cdListingEditorGrid',
  store:cdDataStore,     
  cm: cdColumnModel,      
  enableColLock:false,
  clicksToEdit:1,
  selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:false})
});

cdListingWindow = new Ext.Window({
  id: 'cdListingWindow',
  title: 'some cds',
  closable:true,
  width:700,
  height:350,
  plain:true,
  layout: 'fit',
  items: cdListingEditorGrid
});

cdDataStore.load();     
cdListingWindow.show();   

});
```

Any help or maybe a different approach would be dearly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

which extjs version do you use?

do you made sure the parameter "task" is send? (e.g. using Firefox with Firebug - Network - XHR - Post)

I think proxy itself has no method property.

```
proxy: {
     type: 'ajax',
     url: 'index.php',
     reader: {
         type: 'json',
         root: 'cds'
     },
     extraParams: {
         'task': "LISTING"
     },
     actionMethods: {
        read: 'POST'
    }
 }
```

Your php script must return a json string! e.g. `{'success': true, 'cds':[{"id":"27","titel":"xyz"`

Also your architecture looks strange. Why no separate php file? Why not using a columnmodel? Why do you declare anything as var?